# How do I get the list of branches not merged into master, ordered by most recent commit?

Tags: git

For our buildbot, I want to display the most recently-updated active (non-released) branches.  Let's say I have a `master` branch, as well as the following, from oldest to newest commit:

- `branch1` (not merged into `master`)
- `branch2` (merged)
- `branch3` (not merged)

I am able to get each of these lists separately... e.g. to get all the branches not merged into `master`:

```
$ git branch -r --no-merged origin/master
origin/branch1
origin/branch3
```

Or to get the top fifteen branches, ordered by most recent commit (via https://coderwall.com/p/ndinba):

```
$ git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate --format='%(committerdate:short) %(refname:short)' --count=15 refs/remotes/origin/
2013-03-22 origin/branch3
2013-03-22 origin/branch2
2013-03-22 origin/master
2013-03-22 origin/branch1
```

So I basically want that second list, minus `branch2` (with or without `master`).  Hope that makes sense?

Comment: With git 2.7 (Q4 2015), `git for-each-ref --no-merged master refs/heads/` will be possible! See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32988584/6309)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could combine the two, like this:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate --format="%(committerdate:short) %(refname:short)" --count=15 $(git branch -r --no-merged origin/master | sed -e 's#^ *#refs/remotes/#')
```

That will limit the `for-each-ref` to processing only the branches that `branch --no-merged` reports...

Edit: fixed formatting of `git branch` output after actually testing...

Comment: Not sure where that message comes from - the command line doesn't contain a `>`...  In any case, I updated the command a bit after having a chance to actually try it...

Comment: Hmmm... works for me on git 1.7.11.4 and 1.8.2. Do you have some git aliases set up that might be interfering? If not, test the `git branch ... | sed ...` bit first and make sure it returns just `refs/remotes/origin/somebranch` lines...

Comment: A ha! Found the issue: `git branch ...` was giving back a line with `origin/HEAD -> origin/branchName`.  This worked: `git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate --format="%(committerdate:short) %(refname:short)" --count=15 $(git branch -r --no-merged origin/deployed | grep -v HEAD | sed -e 's#^ *#refs/remotes/#')`

Comment: added solution to dotfiles here: https://github.com/afeld/dotfiles/commit/2547f591b8fac3d1cca3dd9dbf97be0d84a649a9

Comment: *Sigh* I wish StackOverflow had a Copy button for inline code in answers. That long line in the horizontal scrollbar box is a little hard to copy on a touchpad.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just grep out branch2?

Basically, something like:

```
for branch in `git branch -r --no-merged origin/master`; do git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate --format='%(committerdate:short) %(refname:short)' --count=15 refs/remotes/origin/ | grep $branch; done;
```

That worked for me given your sample output.

Comment: `grep: Regular expression too big` haha

Comment: 74, haha.  Need to clean some of those up.

Comment: OK, fine.  Edited for your monstrous case.

Comment: Works!  But can give back fewer than 15, and is a bit slower than the solution from @twalberg.  Also, similar to that one, had to remove the `origin/HEAD -> origin/branchName` line from `git branch ...`.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

With git 2.7 (Q4 2015), [`git for-each-ref`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref), will support the `--no-merged` option

```
git for-each-ref --no-merged master refs/heads/
```

With the doc:

```
--no-merged [<object>]:
```

> Only list refs whose tips are not reachable from the specified commit (HEAD if not specified).

---

See [commit 4a71109](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a71109aa442ba1a7045d36f6b148113c95ffc48), [commit ee2bd06](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee2bd06b0f735a00ce0216ca1d3391b13722d987), [commit f266c91](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f266c9163b34ec55e453d27e1ed246d67ee3ced0), [commit 9d306b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d306b5a6077f026291df3c4a5968eaf95a92417), [commit 7c32834](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c32834813bd6aee5ce5b2c4131d9f34249bc9e3), [commit 35257aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35257aa01203bae74f9fb856fb02c10c4b3836e6), [commit 5afcb90](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5afcb90560586765bf21fb09959a8b4497804639), ..., [commit b2172fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2172fdf702426cb4eba093b5504d0a0e9e59746) (07 Jul 2015), and [commit af83baf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af83bafa4867ba16368e58f36e8311e9591e68f4) (09 Jul 2015) by [Karthik Nayak (`KarthikNayak`)](https://github.com/KarthikNayak).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9958dd8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9958dd8685a0a8b3d6ecdd07e35d8ecb22b304a7), 05 Oct 2015)</sup>

> Some features from "`git tag -l`" and "`git branch -l`" have been made
> available to "`git for-each-ref`" so that eventually the unified
> implementation can be shared across all three, in a follow-up
> series or two.

```
* kn/for-each-tag-branch:
  for-each-ref: add '--contains' option
  ref-filter: implement '--contains' option
  parse-options.h: add macros for '--contains' option
  parse-option: rename parse_opt_with_commit()
  for-each-ref: add '--merged' and '--no-merged' options
  ref-filter: implement '--merged' and '--no-merged' options
  ref-filter: add parse_opt_merge_filter()
  for-each-ref: add '--points-at' option
  ref-filter: implement '--points-at' option
```

---

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), "[`git for-each-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/26a3728bedbdf75c670e21d24f6a30e4673f8d19/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref))</sup> and friends that list refs used to allow only one `--merged` or `--no-merged` to filter them; they learned to take combination of both kind of filtering.

See [commit b59cdff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b59cdffd7e3d791ee289ebb46d7109ad3d51d7ea), [commit a1b19aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1b19aa5d43c46fc570f6946ab5ad001dccc8cdf) (18 Sep 2020), and [commit 21bf933](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21bf933928c02372633b88aa6c4d9d71271d42b3), [commit 415af72](https://github.com/git/git/commit/415af72b174802a45300039ef2bc1127d48dc0c0), [commit b775d81](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b775d8122ecec94a99c1a6588a38455cdd41d8e2) (15 Sep 2020) by [Aaron Lipman (`alipman88`)](https://github.com/alipman88).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 26a3728](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26a3728bedbdf75c670e21d24f6a30e4673f8d19), 22 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`ref-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21bf933928c02372633b88aa6c4d9d71271d42b3): allow `merged` and `no-merged` filters
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Aaron Lipman</sup>

> Enable ref-filter to process multiple `merged` and `no-merged` filters, and extend functionality to [`git branch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/21bf933928c02372633b88aa6c4d9d71271d42b3/Documentation/git-branch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch))</sup> , [`git tag git`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/21bf933928c02372633b88aa6c4d9d71271d42b3/Documentation/git-tag.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag))</sup> and `for-each-ref`.
> This provides an easy way to check for branches that are "graduation candidates:
>
> ```
> $ git branch --no-merged master --merged next
> ```
>
> If passed more than one merged (or more than one `no-merged`) filter, refs must be reachable from any one of the merged commits, and reachable from none of the `no-merged` commits.

`filters` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/21bf933928c02372633b88aa6c4d9d71271d42b3/Documentation/filters.txt#L4-L7):

> When combining multiple `--merged` and `--no-merged` filters, only
> references that are reachable from at least one of the `--merged`
> commits and from none of the `--no-merged` commits are shown.

Note: the same Git 2.29 (Q4 2020) adds an hotfix.

See [commit 5336d50](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5336d5069626a9e06e224cbc1730ee96c5742108) (26 Sep 2020) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 03b0198](https://github.com/git/git/commit/03b0198e304a18dcc83febefd58e30ab1f0aac1e), 04 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`ref-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5336d5069626a9e06e224cbc1730ee96c5742108): plug memory leak in `reach_filter()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> [21bf933928](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21bf933928c02372633b88aa6c4d9d71271d42b3) ("`ref-filter`: allow merged and no-merged filters", 2020-09-15, Git v2.29.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26a3728bedbdf75c670e21d24f6a30e4673f8d19) listed in [batch #16](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e1cfff676549cdcd702cbac105468723ef2722f4)) added an early return to `reach_filter()`.
> Avoid leaking the memory of a then unused array by postponing its allocation until we know we need it.