# Restricting output of "git branch" to certain time period

Tags: git

I am looking for an option to restrict the output of `git branch` to a certain time period. Say, I want all non-merged branches that were still active in the last two months. I can get all branches that are not merged easily with

```
git branch -r --no-merged origin/master
```

but how would I go on filtering those by age of last commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple other answers we can build off of:

- [How can I get a list of git branches, ordered by most recent commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188320/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-git-branches-ordered-by-most-recent-commit)
- [How do I get the list of branches not merged into master, ordered by most recent commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577847/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-branches-not-merged-into-master-ordered-by-most-recent)

The second one contains a good incantation. The subcommand is basically what you have so far, and then [`for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) orders and formats the branches.

```
git for-each-ref \
  --sort=-committerdate \
  --format="%(committerdate:short) %(refname:short)" \
  $(git branch -r --no-merged origin/master | sed -e 's#^ *#refs/remotes/#')
```

```
2015-11-12 origin/something
2015-10-02 origin/another_thing
2015-10-01 origin/so_many_things
2015-09-30 origin/an_older_thing
2014-09-14 origin/a_really_old_thing
```

From there, you can filter for just the last 2 months of changes. There's a nice `awk` solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565450/grep-log-file-greater-than-time-stamp):

```
... | awk '$0 > "2015-10-01"'
```

And then so we don't have to figure out what 2 months ago is every time, `date` can [help us out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168463/using-date-command-to-get-previous-current-and-next-month).

```
date --date='-2 months' +'%Y-%m-%d'
2015-10-01
```

So, altogether, we have:

```
git for-each-ref \
  --sort=-committerdate \
  --format="%(committerdate:short) %(refname:short)" \
  $(git branch -r --no-merged origin/master | sed -e 's#^ *#refs/remotes/#') |\
awk "\$0 > \"$(date --date='-2 months' +'%Y-%m-%d')\""
```

```
2015-11-12 origin/something
2015-10-02 origin/another_thing
2015-10-01 origin/so_many_things
```

Comment: Nice one. I also found those other answers but I am a big fat noob with most command line tools so had no clue how to extend them ;)